# Facebook Graph API data in php array

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

The link

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://givingmode.com/
```

gives me this data

```
{
   "id": "http://givingmode.com/",
   "shares": 3
}
```

Now I am using this script to get the id, shares in a PHP variable

```
    $File= file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://givingmode.com/');
    $p=json_decode($File);
    foreach ($p as $loc)
    {
       $fb_tot_share=$loc->shares;
    }
```

but I don't know what I am doing wrong;

I am getting `$fb_tot_share` as blank.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using it like this?

```
$fb_tot_share=$loc["shares"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
 var link = "http://givingmode.com";
 jQuery.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' + link, function (data) {
   console.log("Shares : " +data[link].shares );
 });
```

OR use this:-

```
    $File= file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://givingmode.com/');
    $p=json_decode($File);
    $fb_tot_share=$p->shares;

    echo $fb_tot_share;


Output : 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
<?php
$File= file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://givingmode.com/');
$obj=json_decode($File);
echo "Total shares: ".$obj->shares;
?>
```